# Count frequency of elements into an array in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have a table in Lua:

```
p = {'sachin', 'sachin', 'dravid', 'Dhoni', 'yuvraj', 'kohli'}
```

I want to count frequency of each name in table .

```
test1 = {sachin=2, dravid=1, Dhoni=1, yuvraj=1, kohli=1}
```

I tried this program with lot of for loops .Please see my code

```
> function exec(ele,p)
count = 0
for k,v in pairs(p) do
if ele == p[k] then
count = count +1 
end
end
return count
end


> new_table = {}
> for k,v in pairs(p) do
new_table[v] = exec(v,p)
end
> 
> for k,v in pairs(new_table) do
print(k,v)
end
dhone   1
yuvraj  1
kohli   1
sachin  2
dravid  1
```

I want to do this more efficient way. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can count the frequency like this:

```
function tally(t)
  local freq = {}
  for _, v in ipairs(t) do
    freq[v] = (freq[v] or 0) + 1
  end
  return freq
end
```

And here's another [**demo example**](http://repl.it/M1a).

Answer (score 1):

Using metatable may be a little unnecessary for this simple case, just showing another option:

```
local mt = {__index = function() return 0 end}
local newtable = {}
setmetatable(newtable, mt)

for _, v in pairs(p) do
    newtable[v] = newtable[v] + 1
end
```

The metamethod `__index` above gives the table `0` as the default value.

Comment: @ms2008vip Ah yes, I tested with the name `t`, but when posted here, I noticed OP used the name `newtable`, so I changed it accordingly, apparently I missed one. Fixed, thanks.